# Can UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection be used in Sun JDK6?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have googled a lot and it seems UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection can only be used in Sun JDK1.4.1. Is it right?

Or this is the default after JDk1.4.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [1.4.2 faq](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html), my bold

> Why is fragmentation a potential problem for the concurrent low pause collector?
>   Normally the concurrent low pause collector does not copy nor compact the live objects. A garbage collection is done without moving the live objects. If fragmentation becomes a problem, allocate a larger heap. **In 1.4.2 if fragmentation in the tenured generation becomes a problem, a compaction of the tenured generation will be done although not concurrently.** In 1.4.1 that compaction will occur if the UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection option is turned on.

I suggest reading [this entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/when_the_sum_of_the) from Jon Masamitsu's blog for an explanation of what is going on.